# Interval between js keypress events and action if keypress event is not occurring

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

In my code below, different words are shown in a `<div>` on a keypress event or after 1500ms if no key is pressed. The elapsed time between the appearance of the word and the keypress is my reaction time and it's saved in the variable `reac`.

This all works fine. But now I'd like to have two adjustments:

1. The reaction time should be equal to 1500 if no key is pressed. As it is now, the time runs through until a key is pressed.
2. I want an Interval of 500ms between the disappearance of an old word and the appearance of the new one.

I assume it's `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, yet I tried and it never worked out perfectly.

Here's my script (I shortened it to make it more readable, so it is possible that I forgot to close a bracket in the example below - hope not though):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var upda = function() {
    (show random word in div)
  };
  t1 = (new Date()).getTime();
  timer = setInterval(upda, 1500);
  $(document).keypress(function(e){
    clearInterval(timer);
    var t2 = (new Date()).getTime();
    reac = t2 - t1;
    t1 = t2;
    if (e.keyCode == 97) {
      (show another random word in div)
    };
    timer = setInterval(upda, 1500);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't really want an [interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval#Callback_arguments), you want a [timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

The general idea is that you set an expiration of 1500ms; if the user hasn't provided the appropriate input by the expiration of that input, your timeout expires and the timeout function fires, setting the default `reac` value and restarting your timer.

The keypress handler would then short-circuit the expiration and record the "actual" `reac`.

As a side note, you probably realize that browser-based JavaScript is a bad choice for any kind of sensitive timing operations, so we'll just go ahead and assume this is for a use case where truly accurate timing data isn't of critical importance. :)

---

**EDIT**

As an exercise, I reworked the code to use timers instead of intervals, and to separate tasks into individual functions. This is only one example; other developers may take different approaches. For example, in a larger project, this would almost certainly be encapsulated in an object library that you could reuse around the application.

```
var expectedInput, inputTimer, reac, startTime;

var $document = $(document);
var defaultReacTime = 1500;
var delayBetweenInputs = 500;
var timerInterval = 1500;

var showWordAndWaitForInput = function () {
    startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    $document.on('keypress', keypressHandler);
    expectedInput = 97;
    console.log('Waiting for <expectedInput> at <startTime> ::', expectedInput, startTime);
    inputTimer = setTimeout(timerExpires, timerInterval);
};

var stopWaitingForInput = function () {
    clearTimeout(inputTimer);
    $document.off('keypress', keypressHandler);
};

var recordReacAndResetTimer = function (reactionTime) {
    reac = reactionTime;
    console.log('reac ::', reac);
    setTimeout(showWordAndWaitForInput, delayBetweenInputs);
};

var timerExpires = function () {
    stopWaitingForInput();
    console.log('timer expired');
    recordReacAndResetTimer(defaultReacTime);
};

var isInputValid = function (e) {
    return e.keyCode === expectedInput;
};

var keypressHandler = function (e) {
    console.log('input received ::', e.keyCode);
    if (isInputValid(e)) {
        console.log('input is valid, ask for new input');
        stopWaitingForInput();
        var endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
        recordReacAndResetTimer(endTime - startTime);
    } else {
        console.log('input is invalid, keep waiting');
    }
};

setTimeout(showWordAndWaitForInput, delayBetweenInputs);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. But my problem is, where exactly do I have to adjust the code. It never worked exactly. In the last block with the keypress event?

Comment: In this example, the easiest thing to do is start over. Rework your code to break each task into a separate function. That will help you keep track of what's going on, and make it much easier to test each unit. See edit above for an example rework.